# Markov Process-Variance of time until jump

Tags: matrix, markov-process, generator

A Markov process on E = {1, 2} is constructed according to holding time parameters λ1 = 2
and λ2 = 4; the defining Markov chain has transition probabilities

p11 = p12 = 0.5

and

p21 = 1.

How do I calculate the generator matrix for this process?

Also what is the variance of the time (starting from state 1) until the process jumps to state
2?

**EDIT**
USING:
\begin{align}
 \nonumber g_{ij} = \left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
      \lambda_i p_{ij} &  \quad \textrm{ if }i \neq j  \\
      &  \quad   \\
    -\lambda_i(1-p_{ii}) &  \quad \textrm{ if }i = j
  \end{array} \right.
\end{align}
I have calculated the generator matrix to be:

```
-1  1
4  -4
```

However I still have no clue how to solve the second part of the question,

Any help would be appreciated

**what is the variance of the time (starting from state 1) until the process jumps to state
2?**

Comment: Your main question is answered on several threads on this site, linked to by a search on [Markov generator](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=markov+generator), so we should consider that part already asked and answered.  Thus respondents should focus on the second question about the variance.

Comment: Are you sure that's your generator matrix? Look at the first row.

Comment: Corrected the generator

Answer (score 0):

Distribution of time out of state '1' is Exponentially distributed with parameter=1, and possibility of jump out of state '1' is only to '2'.

Hence, Distribution of time between jumps to '1' and '2' is$$T\sim exp(-t)$$So, variance of the time (starting from state '1') until the process jumps to state '2' is 1.